# Laravel - Create custom name while uploading image using storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to upload a file using laravel Storage i.e
`$request->file('input_field_name')->store('directory_name');` but it is saving the file in specified directory with random string name.

Now I want to save the uploaded file with **custom name** i.e current timestamp concatenate with actual file name. Is there any fastest and simplest way to achive this functionality.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`storeAs()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#storing-uploaded-files) instead:

```
$request->file('input_field_name')->storeAs('directory_name', time().'.jpg');
```

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, working fine and thank you for quick reply.

Answer (score 6):

You can use below code :

**Use File Facade**

`use Illuminate\Http\File;`

**Make Following Changes in Your Code**

```
$custom_file_name = time().'-'.$request->file('input_field_name')->getClientOriginalName();
$path = $request->file('input_field_name')->storeAs('directory_name',$custom_file_name);
```

For more detail : [Laravel Filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem) And [storeAs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#storing-uploaded-files) as mention by @Alexey Mezenin

Hope this code will help :)

Answer (score 3):

You also can try like this

```
$ImgValue     = $request->service_photo;
$getFileExt   = $ImgValue->getClientOriginalExtension();
$uploadedFile =   time()'.'.$getFileExt;
$uploadDir    = public_path('UPLOAS_PATH');
$ImgValue->move($uploadDir, $uploadedFile);
```

Thanks,

Comment: This is really a simplest way to save file inside public directory :) But I think @BachchaSingh want to achieve this using default Storage. +1 for suggesting the easiest way. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Try with following work :

```
 $image =  time() .'_'. $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();   
 $path = base_path() . '/public/uploads/';
 $request->file('image')->move($path, $image);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this one.

```
$originalName = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
$filename = str_slug(pathinfo($originalName, PATHINFO_FILENAME), "-");
$extension = pathinfo($originalName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$path = public_path('/uploads/');

//Call getNewFileName function 
$finalFullName = $this->getNewFileName($filename, $extension, $path);

// Function getNewFileName 

public function getNewFileName($filename, $extension, $path)
    {

        $i = 1;
        $new_filename = $filename . '.' . $extension;
        while (File::exists($path . $new_filename))
            $new_filename = $filename . '_' . $i++ . '.' . $extension;
        return $new_filename;

    }
```